# Spring's ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource not finding properties file

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-roo, resourcebundle, properties-file

I have two files under the WEB-INF/i18n directory:

- application.properties
- messages.properties

I have properly configured my ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource bean as follows (spring mvc):

```
<bean class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource" id="messageSource" p:basenames="WEB-INF/i18n/messages,WEB-INF/i18n/application"
        p:fallbackToSystemLocale="false"/>
```

and yet I get this from Spring mvc:

```
2012-09-03 02:59:45,911 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource - Loading properties [application.properties]
2012-09-03 02:59:45,912 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource - No properties file found for [WEB-INF/i18n/application_fr] - neither plain properties nor XML
2012-09-03 02:59:45,912 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource - Loading properties [messages.properties]
2012-09-03 02:59:45,912 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource - No properties file found for [WEB-INF/i18n/messages_fr] - neither plain properties nor XML
```

Can anyone please advise? I could move the properties files to the classpath and alter my config accordingly but I'd rather understand what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

In the log message it says this: application_fr

Notice the _fr.
This means its trying to look for the french version of the application.properties (application_fr.properties).
If it cant find the french properties, it should fall back to the default (application.properties), so your props should still be found.
The reason it is looking for the french props is to do with a locale settings somewhere in you app.  Could be from browser, JVM, application.

You can try to add the following, to force the locale to english:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.FixedLocaleResolver" p:defaultLocale="en"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Lithium. As you say it should fall back to `application.properties` so whether I change the name of the file to `application_fr.properties` or I add the code you suggested, I still get the error... Any other idea?

Comment: Well its not an error, its a debug message.  It could be behaving correctly.  Are you finding the incorrect property values?  Also, you should ensure application.properties exists no matter what.  So you could make a copy of application.properties to application_fr.properties .

Comment: Ummm. I don't see what you mean by: **Also, you should ensure application.properties exists no matter what. So you could make a copy of application.properties to application_fr.properties** Having  application_fr.properties and application.properties? I tried that already...